# MySQL Query using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Straight forward question - but for the life of me, can't work out why below shows NO results!!

Was working - all I did was add the WHERE...

```
$query="select distinct c.id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.EmailAddress, c.MemberStatus from details c where c.MemberStatus = 'ACTIVE' order by c.LastName";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr[] = $row;  
}
}
# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

I have do doubt it's something ridiculously simple and I'll look like a goose...

Comment: Ensure you have records having `MemberStatus = ACTIVE`

Comment: Run this and see how many distinct statuses are there in your table: `SELECT DISTINCT MemberStatus FROM details;` **OR** it might be the case that you need to `TRIM` the `MemberStatus ` variable.

Comment: Please post an scheme of the database.

Comment: Please give this a try: `$query="select distinct c.id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.EmailAddress, c.MemberStatus from details c where TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM c.MemberStatus) = 'ACTIVE' order by c.LastName";`

Comment: Whats the value of `$result->num_rows`? Ensure your query is actually returning results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question but are you certain that "ACTIVE" is actually a value that exists in the c.MemberStatus column? A case issue possibly?

Comment: What sound does a Goose make?  Not real sure..  I'll soon be in negative reputation points if I keep this up!!

Comment: Hi @gazza, what was the actual cause of the problem?